# malloc has too many arguments

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I malloc a 2d array. The 2d array is part of a struct and when  I try malloc is I get an error that malloc has too many arguments.

```
malloc(world->representation, sizeof(int *) * mapHeight);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < mapHeight, i++ )
{
    malloc(world->representation[i], sizeof(int) * mapWidth);
}
```

How should this be malloced if its part of a struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `malloc` incorrectly. The proper usage is:

```
world->representation = malloc(sizeof(int *) * mapHeight);
```

and

```
world->representation[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * mapWidth);
```

Answer (score 2):

[malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) takes just the size and returns pointer to the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
world->representation[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * mapWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

malloc returns its memory, it doesn't fill it in. You should also check the return value to make sure it is non-NULL:

```
world->representation = malloc(sizeof(world->representation[0]) * mapHeight);
assert(world->representation);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < mapHeight; ++i) {
    world->representation[i] = malloc(sizeof(word->representation[i][0]) * mapWidth);
    assert(world->representation[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

malloc() has only 1 argument which is the size of the chunk you want allocated, then you'd have to type cast it to the respective pointer type

Most probably your code would be:

```
world->representation = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * mapHeight);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < mapHeight, i++ ) {
    *(world->representation+i) = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * mapWidth);
}
```

Comment: In C you should not cast the return value of malloc. (And in C++ you should generally not allocate simple integer arrays with malloc.)

Comment: @Joe, I do it all the time just to be safe. You never know when your code will be mixed with C++.

Comment: In C, the cast makes it less safe. If you don't know what language you're writing, you should figure that out first.